# Sum of number string not adding integers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program where the user enters a string, such as " 4,3,2,1 " and the integers are added into a sum, which would be 10 in this situation. However I can't find what I need to do next, because at the moment, it only displays 0 as the result, which is int = sum.

[image]

```
private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = numberTextBox.Text.Trim();
        int sum = 0;

        char[] delimiter = { '.' };

        str = str.Trim();

        string[] tokens = str.Split(delimiter);
        foreach (string st in tokens)
        {
            if (IsNumeric(st))
            {
                sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(st);
            }
        }
        resultsLabel.Text = sum.ToString();
    }

    private bool IsNumeric(string st)
    {
        bool numeric = true;

        foreach (char ch in st)
        {

            if(!char.IsDigit(ch))
            {
                numeric = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return numeric;
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're splitting on periods, not commas.  Did you debug this?  You should have noticed that `4,3,2,1` is not getting split.

Comment: Oh my god, you are right... I mistyped the symbol and spent 15 minutes staring at this. That fixed it, thanks.